# Adding nested json in tables - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, associations

I am new to ruby on rails and I am trying to store nested json in the table.

```
 json: 
 articles: {
  title: "abc",
  text: "a",
  address: {
    flat: "abc",
    city: "bang"
   }
  } 

Migrations:
 class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
   def change
     create_table :articles do |t|
       t.string :title
       t.text :text
       t.string :address

       t.timestamps
     end
  end
 end

class CreateAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :addresses do |t|
      t.string :flat
      t.string :city

      t.timestamps
   end
  end
end



 models:
 class Article < ApplicationRecord

   has_one :address
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
 end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
end


 controller:
 class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

    def create
      @article = Article.new(params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :address))

     @article.save
     redirect_to @article
   end


   def show
     @article = Article.find(params[:id])
   end
end


form(new.html.erb):
    <%= form_with scope: :article, url: articles_path, local: true do |form| %>
   <p>
     <%= form.label :title %><br>
     <%= form.text_field :title %>
   </p>

<p>
  <%= form.label :text %><br>
  <%= form.text_area :text %>
</p>

<%=form.fields_for :address do |a| %>
    <div>
      <%=a.label :flat%><br>
      <%= a.text_field :flat%><br>

      <%=a.label :city%><br>
      <%= a.text_field :city%>
    </div>
<%end%>
<p>
  <%= form.submit %>
</p>
```

I am not able to store the adrress to the table. address is always saved as nil.  Can anyone guide me if what i am doing wrong. I want to parse the json to the table and store the json as string. Updated the question with controller and form that i am using.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Can you please add  controller code how you are going to store json with permitted params ?

Comment: updated with controller.

Comment: Add your form and params that you are getting after submitting form.

Comment: added the new.html.erb file that is used for form submit.

Comment: If you are going to store whole json into a string `address` in your `Article` model then why do you create another address table as you mentioned in question 'parse the json to the table and store the json as string' ?

Comment: I was not sure what should be better approach to handle this scenario. but later realised i can go ahead with storing nested address as string. your suggestions are welcome if you feel there is a better way to do it.

Comment: I think what you are trying to do is Rails Forms with Nested Attributes. Google it you will get good tutorials follow them and then ask your query if any  Thanks.

Comment: okay.. Thankyou..

Comment: In order to use accepts_nested_attributes_for with strong parameters, you need to specify which nested attributes should be whitelisted. Check this [link](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)

Answer (score 1):

When you want to permit nested attributes you do specify the attributes of nested object within an array. Pls, try this one `@article = params.require(:articles).permit(:text, :title, :address =>[:flat, :city])`
Rails has a very good documentation pls take a look https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit